# Animation method applyTransformation not triggered until I click any layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

This is so weird, I've this animation code:

```
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
private View mAnimatedView;
private MarginLayoutParams mViewLayoutParams;
private int mMarginStart, mMarginEnd;
private boolean mWasEndedAlready = false;

/**
* Initialize the animation
* @param view The layout we want to animate
* @param duration The duration of the animation, in ms
*/
    public ExpandAnimation(View view, int duration) {
        setDuration(duration);
        mAnimatedView = view;
        mViewLayoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        mMarginStart = mViewLayoutParams.rightMargin;
        mMarginEnd = (mMarginStart == 0 ? (0- view.getWidth()) : 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            // Calculating the new bottom margin, and setting it
            mViewLayoutParams.rightMargin = mMarginStart
                    + (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);
            // Invalidating the layout, making us seeing the changes we made
            mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

        // Making sure we didn't run the ending before (it happens!)
        } else if (!mWasEndedAlready) {
            mViewLayoutParams.rightMargin = mMarginEnd;
            mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
            mWasEndedAlready = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And I use this Animation:

```
View parent = (View) v.getParent();
View containerMenu = parent.findViewById(R.id.containerMenu);
ExpandAnimation anim=new ExpandAnimation(containerMenu, 1000);
containerMenu.startAnimation(anim);
```

This animation toggle a layout hidding / showing it.

By default, its hidden. When I click, animation works and it's shown. When I click again, it shrinks correctly. But the 3rd time, it does nothing. I've debugged and I found out that the constructor is called **but not** `applyTransformation`. 
**Somehow, if I click any layout around the screen, the animation suddenly starts.**

Any idea?

**Edit**
Does anyone know WHEN is applyTransformation triggered?

Comment: I'm using the same code, and have the exact same problem. applyTranformation is never called the third or subsequent times. It's like the animation needs to be reset on the view somehow. I've tried calling containerMenu.clearAnimation() but it doesn't help.

Comment: I've been fighting it for many hours, and still without result...

Comment: @NetWolf I managed to find a workaround. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't understand why, but when I click or do any action to any layout, the animation finally starts. So I programatically added a workaround. I've a scrollview in my layout, so I move the scroll position:

```
hscv.scrollTo(hscv.getScrollX()+1, hscv.getScrollY()+1);
```

This just after `containerMenu.startAnimation(anim);`

This just works, I can't understand why.

Also, I found out that some animations worked flawless on android > 4, but on 2.3 for instance, it had the same issue, worked to expand, and to shrink, but not to expand for the second time.

```
parent.invalidate();
```

Did the trick.

Comment: Mine is inside a Fragment which is inside a ViewPager. I can work around it by getting the activity's viewpager instance and scrolling by 1 pixel and then scolling back after calling the animation. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @NetWolf I've just added `parent.invalidate();`. Seems to work on 2.3 devices.

Comment: I had just found the same thing now that I got to test on an old phone. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Exactly this solution saves my day !!