# Custom ScaleAnimation / applytransformation is not called

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

This is my custom ScaleAnimation:

```
public class MyScaler extends ScaleAnimation {

    private static final String TAG = "myScaler";

    private View mView;

    private LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

    private int oldMargin, newMargin;

    private boolean mVanishAfter = false;

    public MyScaler(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int duration, View view,
            boolean vanishAfter) {
        super(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
        setDuration(duration);
        setFillAfter(true);
        setFillBefore(true);
        setFillEnabled(true);
        mView=view;

        int height = 200; // fiktive hoehe

        mLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        oldMargin = toY<fromY ? mLayoutParams.bottomMargin : -214;
        Log.d(TAG, "old Margin "+oldMargin);
        newMargin = toY<fromY ? oldMargin-height : height;
        Log.d(TAG, "new Margin "+newMargin);

    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        Log.d(TAG, "apply transofrmation");
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            int newBottomMargin=(int)(newMargin*interpolatedTime) + oldMargin;
            mLayoutParams.setMargins(mLayoutParams.leftMargin, mLayoutParams.topMargin,
                    mLayoutParams.rightMargin, newBottomMargin);
            Log.d(TAG,"margin change "+newBottomMargin);
            mView.getParent().requestLayout();
        } else if (mVanishAfter) {
            mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am calling it like this, to get a expand and hide it via a toggle button:

```
toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick first "+first);
            if(first){
                myScale = new MyScaler(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 500, dp, false);
                ((TextView) v).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.expander_ic_minimized, 0);
            }
            else{
                myScale = new MyScaler(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 500, dp, false);
                ((TextView) v).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.expander_ic_maximized, 0);
            }
            first=!first;
            myScale.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    first= !first;
                    Log.d(TAG, "change First"+first);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "started ani");
                }

            });

            dp.startAnimation(myScale);
            View parent = (View)dp.getParent();
             parent.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

It hides the View at the first attempt the right way. But everytime I want to expand it via the Button, it does not happen. If touch the over views, the animation starts. What do I have to change? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue but invalidate didn't work in my case. This solved my issue:

```
dp.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who calls to `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` do not work, try

`((View) view.getParent()).invalidate()`

as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657563/752781

Answer (score 2):

Callig the `invalidate()` method on a visible `View` object just after the `startAnimation(Animation)` method helped me.