# background color stop my animation

Tags: android, animation

I have a problem with a button , if add him background my animation stop work.

Here is xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/coinsbackground" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/instructiuni"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/instructiuneinceput" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/instructiuniInceputHtml"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#8CFAFAFA" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/terminareinceput" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/intructiuni" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/instructiuniHtml"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#8CFAFAFA"  />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back_instructiuni"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Back >>"
                    android:background="#5B52D7" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="18" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playgame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/instructions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Instructions"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#5B52D7" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My animation class:

```
    public class FlipWidthAnimation extends Animation {


    private int startWidth;
    private int deltaWidth; // distance between start and end height
    private View view;

    /**
     * constructor, do not forget to use the setParams(int, int) method before
     * starting the animation
     * @param v
     */
    public FlipWidthAnimation(View v) {
        this.view = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

        view.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (startWidth + deltaWidth * interpolatedTime);
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    /**
     * set the starting and ending height for the resize animation
     * starting height is usually the views current height, the end height is the height
     * we want to reach after the animation is completed
     * @param start height in pixels
     * @param end height in pixels
     */
    public void setParams(int start, int end) {

        this.startWidth = start;
        deltaWidth = end - startWidth;
    }

    /**
     * set the duration for the hideshowanimation
     */
    @Override
    public void setDuration(long durationMillis) {
        super.setDuration(durationMillis);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here event:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.instructions){
        LinearLayout instructiuni = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.instructiuni);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) instructiuni.getLayoutParams();
        FlipWidthAnimation a = new FlipWidthAnimation(instructiuni);
        a.setDuration(1000);

        a.setParams(lp.width, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
        instructiuni.startAnimation(a);
    }
```

he come in event is not a problem i debuged i see no error , but animation not started , but for example if click on settings animation started if was presset instructions before press settings. realy have no ideea why .

Comment: Be more precise. Which button is doing problems?

Comment: can u try like this   android:background="@color/Blue"

Comment: instructions button is problem , if put android:background="color" i see he clicked he execute all event but animation no start only if press other button , example settings.

Comment: GB_Bhayani , i dont have @color/Blue only @color/abc_search_url_text_normal and steel don't work

Comment: if is posible my color influence my weight .. or i can't examplin

Comment: I found the solution only need invalidate() my button : [here is link who help me][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973913/custom-scaleanimation-applytransformation-is-not-called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to give invalidate() my button: [here is link who help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973913/custom-scaleanimation-applytransformation-is-not-called)